# Binding to a collections of objects

Tags: svelte

I have a map of objects and need to bind some fields of them to  tags. I can convert the map to an array and use #each, of course, but in this case, an update to a single Map entry will update bindings to all  tags. I would like atomic updates, i.e. binding inputs to separate objects, while using #each for constructing the whole stuff (mapping 50 or so items manually is not fun). Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you provide a simplified code example. It feels like you need to have an unique index for each entry or use `#each`’s index feature (https://svelte.dev/docs#each)

Comment: Actually, it is hard to provide code example, because this is my question :) But as another description, I need to bind 50 objects to <input> tags. Not using an array (#each), as an update to a single aray item would update all the bound <input> tags. Do not want to construct the whole 50 <input> tags by hand, as well.

Comment: Here is the solution: https://svelte.dev/repl/d0b90cca3c904a7c8f9555de1a1e6cf5?version=3.29.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (hacky somehow) is below:

App.svelte:

```
    <script>
    import Update from "./Update.js"
    
        let items = [
        { id: 1, value: 'a' },
        { id: 2, value: 'b' },
        { id: 3, value: 'c' },
        { id: 4, value: 'd' },
        { id: 5, value: 'e' }
    ];
   </script>

   <style>
    :global(.myclass) {
        animation: pulse 2s ease-out
    }
    
    @keyframes pulse {
     0%, 75% {
       background-color: red;
     }
     100% {
       background-color: white;
    }
   }
</style>

{#each items as item (item.id)}
    <input type="text" bind:value={item.value} use:Update={item.value}>
{/each}
```

The Update.js action:

```
 export default function update(node, foo) {
 let faa = foo
 return {
     update(foo) {
       if (foo === faa) return
       faa = foo
       // rest of code will only be executed if the value really changed
       node.style.animation = 'none';
       node.offsetHeight; /* trigger reflow */
       node.style.animation = null; 
       node.classList.add("myclass");
     }
   }
 }
```